# Loading a combo box with all system colors in wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox, colors, systemcolors

I have created combo box that I would like to load with all of the standard colors. I would like to do this in the xaml.cs file rather than the straight XAML. I have found many examples to do this in the C# for .NET but not WPF.

I found the following code that runs in .NET and it seems that `prop.PropertyType.FullName` never equals `"System.Drawing.Color")` I debugged through it and the only value that System.Reflection.PropertyInfo eqauls that makes sense is System.Windows.Media.ColorContext. But when i tried this it did not return any colors.

```
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Color).GetProperties())
{
if (prop.PropertyType.FullName == "System.Drawing.Color")
comboBox1.Items.Add(prop.Name);
}
```

Any Suggestions or comments are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  Try a Debug.  You may be getting the colors but the problem is with is add items.

```
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info in typeof(Colors).GetProperties())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(info.Name);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks!. I guess i didnt need that if statment

Answer (score 1):

You can import the style via a `ResourceDictionary`

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/PresentationFramework.Aero;V4.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
```

And apply the style of the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code gets the properties of `Color` and not `Colors`
2. The colors in that class are of type `System.Windows.Media.Color` (instead of `System.Drawing.Color`)